# can a JavaScript Array be null?

Tags: javascript

I'm Collecting JavaScript Classes prototypes that make it compatible to old browsers never mind of that but what i wonder while collecting them that the Developer At Mozila comparing the Array to null i can see that is non since but maybe I'm wrong and there is an explanation for that ???

```
 if (!Array.prototype.every) {
    Array.prototype.every = function(fun /*, thisp */) {
        "use strict";

        if (this == null)
            throw new TypeError();

        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun != "function")
            throw new TypeError();

        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in t && !fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
}
```

at this line

```
 if (this == null)
```

this is refers to the Array

This code at [Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Kindly i need an explanation is that a logic to compare a Array to a null even if i know that "this" which is refer to a must array type not a variable can be array or null ?? what you think ??

Answer (score 4):

It could happen when someone calls it without a context, e.g. `Array.prototype.every(...)` instead of `someArray.every(...)`. Or a more likely case: Passing `someArray.every` as a callback to some other function which will then invoke it without the proper context.

Since the function is running in [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) `this === undefined` when no context is provided. And `undefined == null`.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful for cases like:

```
Array.prototype.every.call(null, ...);
```

You are not likely to meet that version of code, but in place of `null` can be a variable, that is not yet initialized, for example. In that case `TypeError` is only logical.

Comment: You are missing the most important detail. Normally, when you pass `null` to `.call` (or `.apply`), `this` will refer to `window`. Test: `(function() { console.log(this); }.call(null));`